# Can I change the object of a WeakReference has?

Tags: kotlin

Can I change `b` to have `a2` instead of `a1`?

```
class A{};

fun main()
{
    val a1 = A();
    val a2 = A();
    val b = WeakReference(a1);
    b.change(a2);//hypothetical
```

Comment: Nope...........

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I was trying to set an initial value to avoid making it a ? type and then set the object later. But oh well, if there is no way, I will just create a new one.